# Raster does not clip according to polygon feature

Tags: raster, polygon, clip

I'm trying to cut my raster to fit a polygon, but it keeps doing this weird thing pictured below. I've tried the following things:

- Merging and dissolving the polygon into 1 polygon
- Converting the polygon to a raster

Neither has worked. Any ideas on how I can solve this?
[image]

Comment: Have you tried [Clip](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/clip.htm) with your polygon as `clipping_geometry`? Should work

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: It's likely that your clip geometry is corrupt (wrong ring rotation). You need to repair the geometry before you can use it.

Answer (score -1):

I repaired the clip geometry and I also checked the "Use input features for clipping geometry" box which I don't think I did before? Stupid. It works now anyway.

Thanks for your help!